# How to calculate position and size relative to screen, move to monitor and restore ratio

Tags: math, autohotkey

I'm trying to create a program that will capture a windows x,y position and w,h ratios compared to the monitor it happens to be on.  Then, the program will hide the window until it is released.  It will release on the monitor that the program's main gui has been moved to when a button is clicked.  When the window is released, it will show and position itself in the same way it originally was, just on the new monitor.  So far, everything is working except the position and size pieces.

I'm using only the work areas of the monitors and I have 3 monitors set up. Their coordinates are as follows:

#### 1 (primary center monitor)

Left:    0

Top:     0

Right:   1366

Bottom:  738

#### 2 (right monitor)

Left:    1366

Top:     -652

Right:   3286

Bottom:  398

#### 3 (left monitor)

Left:    -1920

Top:     -864

Right:   0

Bottom:  186

For a visual representation, here's what they look like virtually:

[image: visual]

As you can see, the left and right monitors are 1920x1080, however my middle one is actually a laptop and has a smaller resolution at 1366x768

Code-wise, I've tried several things but the latest attempt is as follows:

When storing the values,

```
Sysget monstart, Monitor, %currentMonitorIndex%
WinGetPos, answerWinx, answerWiny, answerWinw, answerWinh, %title%
if( monstartLeft <= 0 ) ; check if this is the left monitor and has negative coordinates
{
    if( monstartRight = 0 ) ; change 0 to 1 to prevent dividing by 0
    {
        monstartRight = 1
    }
    ; get ratios for the position and size relative to monitor
    ratiox := answerWinx / monstartRight
    ratioy := answerWiny / monstartBottom
    ratiow := ( answerWinx + answerWinw ) / monstartRight
    ratioh := ( answerWiny + answerWinh ) / monstartBottom
}
else
{
    ratiox := answerWinx / monstartLeft
    ratioy := answerWiny / monstartBottom
    ratiow := ( answerWinx + answerWinw ) / monstartLeft
    ratioh := ( answerWiny + answerWinh ) / monstartBottom
}
```

Then when trying to restore the window:

```
cubeIndex := GetMonitorIndexFromWindow( hGui1 )
SysGet, monit, Monitor, %cubeIndex%
monitWidth := monitRight - monitLeft
monitHeight := monitBottom - monitTop
if( monitLeft >= 0 )
{
    winNewX := monitLeft + ( ratiox * ( monitRight - monitLeft ) )
    winNewY := monitTop + ( ratioy * ( monitBottom - monitTop ) )
    winNewW := ratiow * monitRight
    winNewH := ratioh * monitBottom
    winNewWidth := winNewW - winNewX
    winNewHeight := winNewH - winNewY
}
else
{
    winNewX := ratiox * monitLeft
    winNewY := ratioy * monitBottom
    winNewW := ratiow * monitLeft
    winNewH := ratioh * monitBottom
    winNewWidth := abs( winNewW - winNewX )
    winNewHeight := abs( winNewH - winNewY )
}
ratiox := ratiox
ratioy := ratioy
ratiow := ratiow
ratioh := ratioh

WinMove, %title%,, winNewX, winNewY, winNewWidth, winNewHeight
WinActivate, %title%
```

I had it working before when I hid and restored on the same monitor.  Since then I've changed it and now it makes the window reappear off monitor.  I've been staring at this and flipping values around for so long I'm confusing myself.  I just need a second pair of eyes on this if you have the time.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**  Following the link posted below, the code that ended up working perfectly is as follows:

For storing the values:

```
ratiox := ( answerWinx - monstartLeft ) / ( monstartRight - monstartLeft )
ratioy := ( answerWiny - monstartTop ) / ( monstartBottom - monstartTop )
ratiow := ( ( answerWinx + answerWinw ) - monstartLeft ) / ( monstartRight - monstartLeft )
ratioh := ( ( answerWiny + answerWinh ) - monstartTop ) / ( monstartBottom - monstartTop )
```

and for retrieving them:

```
winNewX := monitLeft + ( monitRight - monitLeft ) * ratiox
winNewY := monitTop + ( monitBottom - monitTop ) * ratioy
winNewW := monitLeft + ( monitRight - monitLeft ) * ratiow
winNewH := monitTop + ( monitBottom - monitTop ) * ratioh
winNewWidth := winNewW - winNewX
winNewHeight := winNewH - winNewY
```

Comment: You may wanna look at this script: https://github.com/T-vK/WinMover/blob/master/WinMover.ahk It moves the active Window to the next screen when pressing Win+Enter.

Comment: Thank you for the link!  I incorporated that math and it yielded the results I was hoping for.  Incase anyone else comes looking, I'll edit the main post with the answer

Comment: Great! You should add this as a new answer instead, though. It's okay to answer your own questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Forivin's suggestion, here is the answer I found

For storing the values:

```
ratiox := ( answerWinx - monstartLeft ) / ( monstartRight - monstartLeft )
ratioy := ( answerWiny - monstartTop ) / ( monstartBottom - monstartTop )
ratiow := ( ( answerWinx + answerWinw ) - monstartLeft ) / ( monstartRight - monstartLeft )
ratioh := ( ( answerWiny + answerWinh ) - monstartTop ) / ( monstartBottom - monstartTop )
```

and for retrieving them:

```
winNewX := monitLeft + ( monitRight - monitLeft ) * ratiox
winNewY := monitTop + ( monitBottom - monitTop ) * ratioy
winNewW := monitLeft + ( monitRight - monitLeft ) * ratiow
winNewH := monitTop + ( monitBottom - monitTop ) * ratioh
winNewWidth := winNewW - winNewX
```

winNewHeight := winNewH - winNewY